# Javascript - Large background image load time is holding up my onLoad function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a beautiful background image on a website which unfortunately takes a while to load. The rest of my page is driven by a function that is called when the body loads like so:

```
<body onLoad="initialise()">
      ...
```

Because of this, my browser is waiting for the background to fully load before calling initialise(). How can i either call initialise() before the page fully loads or at least before the background image does.

Thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to wait til the page is ready, try using jQuery's ready event instead:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>jQuery(document).ready(initialise)</script>
```

This will run before images are loaded, but will wait for all HTML.

Answer (score 6):

Just add this right before the `</body>` tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">initialise();</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help and for such a quick reply. This fixed it, but i'm going to use the $.ready function that somebody else posted :) Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

use jquery's ready() method. if you aren't using jquery, check this out:
http://code.google.com/p/domready/
It's a small library just for this work.

Answer (score 1):

If initialise() does not depend on any page element to be there then you can just call it the head

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    initialise();
</script>
```

If initialise() need page elements then put the above script at the bottom of the html page or use jquery document ready